# Hexagonal grid cells sometimes overflow container

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I am trying to make a hexagonal grid (pointy ends vertical) using only CSS, with [this article](https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/) as a guide. My approach is to have a `block` container with `inline-block` children as the cells. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes the final few cells overflow the parent. I am at a loss as to why, after working at this for several hours.

[Correct behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMb5S.png)
[Incorrect behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZL04.png)

I have tried many combinations of `box-sizing`, `flex-basis`, `height`, `min-height`, `margin`, `padding`, `overflow`, etc. to no avail. I have tested this on Chrome and Firefox on two different devices. I just want the container element's content box to fit around its content. I find it very strange that sometimes the container's content box just does not include some of its children.

```css
/* global.css */

:root {
  --color0: #393646;
  --color1: #4F4557;
  --color2: #6D5D6E;
  --color3: #F4EEE0;
  background-color: var(--color3);
}

* {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--color0);
  border-color: var(--color1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

button, input[type=submit] {
  border: none;
  color: var(--color3);
  background-color: var(--color0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

fieldset {
  border-width: 1px;
}

legend {
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  line-height: 1px;
}

/* map.css */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  --hex-columns: 14;
  --hex-span: 50px;
  --hex-diameter: calc(1.1547 * var(--hex-span));
  --hex-triameter: calc(1.5 * var(--hex-diameter) - 0.2px);
  --hex-overlap: calc(-0.25 * var(--hex-diameter));
  flex-basis: max-content;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  width: calc(var(--hex-columns) * var(--hex-span) + 0.2px);
  overflow: hidden; /* DEBUG, to show when content overflows */
  font-size: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: calc(var(--hex-span) / 2);
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: repeating-linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent 0 calc(var(--hex-triameter) - 3px),
    black calc(var(--hex-triameter) - 3px) var(--hex-triameter)
  );
}

.container .hex {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: var(--hex-overlap);
  padding: 0px;
  width: var(--hex-span);
  height: var(--hex-diameter);
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: var(--hex-diameter);
  font-size: initial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 0% 75%, 50% 100%, 100% 75%, 100% 25%, 50% 0%);
}

.container .hex:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* For debug: */

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/map.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Repeat a bunch of times -->
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
        <div class="hex"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem lies with the form of the before element. Just to start, where does the 3px come from?

Comment: @AHaworth To quote the linked article, "In order to push the second row over to the right, we need few pixel of opaque color so A can simply be equal to B - Xpx, where X is a small value." It's just an arbitrary amount.

Answer (score 0):

The article that you linked to addresses this issue: [Fighting the overflow](https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/#aa-fighting-the-overflow)

"The fix is to add some padding-bottom to our container. I will make the padding equal to the height of one shape"

So in your case, you want something like this:

```
.container {
  padding-bottom: var(--hex-span);
}
```

```css
/* global.css */

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}


/* map.css */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  --hex-columns: 14;
  --hex-span: 50px;
  --hex-diameter: calc(1.1547 * var(--hex-span));
  --hex-triameter: calc(1.5 * var(--hex-diameter) - 0.2px);
  --hex-overlap: calc(-0.25 * var(--hex-diameter));
  flex-basis: max-content;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: var(--hex-span);
  width: calc(var(--hex-columns) * var(--hex-span) + 0.2px);
  overflow: hidden; /* DEBUG, to show when content overflows */
  font-size: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: calc(var(--hex-span) / 2);
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: repeating-linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent 0 calc(var(--hex-triameter) - 3px),
    black calc(var(--hex-triameter) - 3px) var(--hex-triameter)
  );
}

.container .hex {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: var(--hex-overlap);
  padding: 0px;
  width: var(--hex-span);
  height: var(--hex-diameter);
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: var(--hex-diameter);
  font-size: initial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 0% 75%, 50% 100%, 100% 75%, 100% 25%, 50% 0%);
}

.container .hex:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* For debug: */

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.container .hex:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Repeat a bunch of times -->
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
    <div class="hex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try this; however, sometimes there is no overflow at the bottom, and this adds extra space at the bottom of the container that I don't need. The issue is that there is strangely only overflow _sometimes_.